# Upload multipart/form-data file in Spring boot and REST API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, storage, multipartform-data

I want to upload a .png file and storage that.when I send it with content-type=multipart/form-data I receive this Exception

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 
  'application/octet-stream' not supported .
```

I think my application doesn't understand form-data contentType and throws an irrelevant exception. What's wrong?

```java
    @Controller
    public class ProfileController {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileController.class);

        @Autowired
        ProfileService service;

        //http : http --pretty all --form PUT localhost:8080/profile/v1?thumb=glb
        @PutMapping(value = "/v1")
        public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> upload(@RequestPart(value = "thumb", required = false) String thumbFilterName,
                                                   @RequestPart(value = "genthumb", required = false) String genthumb,
                                                   @RequestPart("hash") String hash,
                                                   @RequestPart("uploader") Long uploader,
                                                   @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {


        System.out.println(thumbFilterName);
        System.out.println(gentumb);
        System.out.println(uploader);
        System.out.println(file);
//and doing storage stuff!
return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
        }
    }
```

and this is my Rest Client that is used for sending file. Pay attention to response.

These are screenshots of restClient. Sending file with restClient:

[image: sending file with restClient]

And this is setting headers

[image: and this is setting headers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `uploader` you must change `@RequestPart` to `@RequestParam`

```
@RequestPart("uploader") Long uploader,
```

[Javadoc explaination](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html):

> Note that @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument supporting the same method argument types. The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String, @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor while @RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConverters taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request part. @RequestParam is likely to be used with name-value form fields while @RequestPart is likely to be used with parts containing more complex content (e.g. JSON, XML).

Comment: hi , realy realy thanks for replying , it's worked :)